# jquery using .submit() form not submitting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am submitting a form using jQuery but when I use JavaScript it is submitted but through jQuery it is not submitting.

Here is my form code:

```
<form method="post" id="uploadfrm" action="<?php echo site_url('filemanager/upload'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="up_wraper">Click here to Select a File </div>
<input type="file" name="upload[]" id="upload" multiple="multiple" /> </form>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready( function() {
       $("#upload").change( function() { 
        var value=$("#foo").val();
        var file=$("#upload").val();
        var arr = value.split("_");
        var id = arr[1];
        var type = arr[0];

        if(type!='folder'){
            alert('Select a folder to upload files..!');
            }
          else{
                 $("#foo").val(id);
                 $('#uploadfrm').submit( function(event) {
                 event.preventDefault();

                 });

            }
       });
   });
</script>
```

When I use in else condition:

```
document.forms["uploadfrm"].submit();
```

it submits successfully.

But I want to submit it using jQuery using `preventDefault()` method.

Comment: So you want to submit a form, but prevent it from submitting?

Comment: Why you want event.preventDefault();it prevents from form submission

Comment: By using preventdefault form submit but its not refresh the browser window..

Comment: Delete this line `event.preventDefault();` and the form will submit i think.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have this...

```
$('#uploadfrm').submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The 2nd line, `event.preventDefault();`, stops the form submitting.  If you remove that it will submit fine.  Just do this...

```
$('#uploadfrm').submit();
```

Comment: @saqlain786 Huh? Not it isn't. `preventDefault` does exactly what it says on the tin. The event still occurs, but the form does not submit. Don't get them confused.

Comment: @ BenM hmmm..ok i am just trying..wait a moment.

Comment: saqlain786 - if this isn't what you need then give us a bit more info.  The submit and refresh are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need event.preventDefault(); 
Simple  `$('#uploadfrm').submit();` triggers form submission.
However, if you want to process some validations before submission, 
you can add another $.submit();  before your submission trigger.

```
    $('#uploadfrm').submit(function(){
      //your code goes here. 
     //return false; //if you want to break submission on failed validation, or if you want to use ajax callback
     //return true; // if you want to submit with regular form request. 
    });

   //this line bellow goes in your conditional, while upper one goes out of your $('#upload').change(); //event
   $('#uploadfrm').submit();
```